# In Java, what purpose do the keywords `final`, `finally` and `finalize` fulfil? 

Tags: java, final, finally, finalize

In Java, what purpose do the keywords `final`, `finally` and `finalize` fulfil?

Comment: Homework question?  http://allu.wordpress.com/2006/11/08/difference-between-final-finally-and-finalize/

Comment: They're not even comparable concepts. They just happen to be spelled similarly. Do some reading.

Comment: They have nothing to do with each other - totally unrelated, conceptually.  Study each separately.

Comment: @Gray no, I found something about this and I was wondering what is the difference

Comment: This should not be closed as it appears to be a relatively common question.

Comment: voted to reopen due to a good answer, which may be useful for users who lands here.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

## final

`final` can be used to mark a variable "unchangeable"

```
private final String name = "foo";  //the reference name can never change
```

`final` can also make a method not "overrideable"

```
public final String toString() {  return "NULL"; }
```

`final` can also make a class not "inheritable". i.e. the class can not be subclassed.

```
public final class finalClass {...}
public class classNotAllowed extends finalClass {...} // Not allowed
```

## finally

`finally` is used in a try/catch statement to [execute code "always"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

```
lock.lock();
try {
  //do stuff
} catch (SomeException se) {
  //handle se
} finally {
  lock.unlock(); //always executed, even if Exception or Error or se
}
```

Java 7 has a [new try with resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) that you can use to automatically  close resources that explicitly or implicitly implement [java.io.Closeable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) or [java.lang.AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)

## finalize

`finalize` is called when an object is garbage collected.  You rarely need to override it.  An example:

```
protected void finalize() {
  //free resources (e.g. unallocate memory)
  super.finalize();
}
```

Comment: better answer than most of Java books !!

Comment: Thank you. This answer is well explained in compare to others called them selves "experts".

Comment: Good answer but the signature of finalize method is wrong.

Comment: **Note:** The [`Object#finalize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) method was deprecated in Java 9 ([JDK-8165641](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8165641)).

Answer (score 19):

- "Final" denotes that something cannot be changed. You usually want to use this on static variables that will hold the same value throughout the life of your program.
- "Finally" is used in conjunction with a try/catch block. Anything inside of the "finally" clause will be executed regardless of if the code in the 'try' block throws an exception or not.
- "Finalize" is called by the JVM before an object is about to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 6):

http://allu.wordpress.com/2006/11/08/difference-between-final-finally-and-finalize/

> final – constant declaration.
>
> finally – The finally block always executes when the try block exits, except System.exit(0) call. This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs. But finally is useful for more than just exception handling — it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break. Putting cleanup code in a finally block is always a good practice, even when no exceptions are anticipated.
>
> finalize() – method helps in garbage collection. A method that is invoked before an object is discarded by the garbage collector, allowing it to clean up its state. Should not be used to release non-memory resources like file handles, sockets, database connections etc because Java has only a finite number of these resources and you do not know when the garbage collection is going to kick in to release these non-memory resources through the finalize() method.

Did you try searching on google, and need clarification for an explanation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this article may in fact answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Stack Overflow is only as useful as its questions and answers, and if this blog host goes down or URLs get moved around, this answer becomes useless. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The final keyword is used to declare constants.

```
final int FILE_TYPE = 3;
```

The finally keyword is used in a try catch statement to specify a block of code to execute regardless of thrown exceptions.

```
try
{
  //stuff
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  //do stuff
}
finally
{
  //this is always run
}
```

And finally (haha), finalize im not entirely sure is a keyword, but there is a [finalize()](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/gc/finalize.html) function in the Object class.

Answer (score 6):

final:
    **final is a keyword.** The variable decleared as final should be
    initialized only once and cannot be changed. Java classes
    declared as final cannot be extended. Methods declared as final
    cannot be overridden.

finally:
    **finally is a block.** The finally block always executes when the
    try block exits. This ensures that the finally block is executed
    even if an unexpected exception occurs. But finally is useful for
    more than just exception handling - it allows the programmer to
    avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return,
    continue, or break. Putting cleanup code in a finally block is
    always a good practice, even when no exceptions are anticipated.

finalize:
    **finalize is a method.** Before an object is garbage collected, the
    runtime system calls its finalize() method. You can write system
    resources release code in finalize() method before getting garbage
    collected.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Final**
•   Final is used to apply restrictions on class, method and variable.
•   Final class can't be inherited, final method can't be overridden and final variable value can't be changed. 
•   Final variables are initialized at the time of creation except in case of blank final variable which is initialized in Constructor.
•   Final is a keyword.

**2. Finally**
•   Finally is used for exception handling along with try and catch.
•   It will be executed whether exception is handled or not.
•   This block is used to close the resources like database connection, I/O resources.
•   Finally is a block.

**3. Finalize**
•   Finalize is called by Garbage collection thread just before collecting eligible objects to perform clean up processing.
•   This is the last chance for object to perform any clean-up but since it’s not guaranteed that whether finalize () will be called, its bad practice to keep resource till finalize call.
•   Finalize is a method.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of final in java is:
-applied to a variable means that the respective variable once initialized can no longer be modified

```
private final double numer = 12;
```

If you try to modify this value, you will get an error.

-applied to a method means that the respective method can't be override

```
 public final void displayMsg()
    {
        System.out.println("I'm in Base class - displayMsg()");
    }
```

But final method can be inherited because final keyword restricts the redefinition of the method.

-applied to a class means that the respective class can't be extended.

```
class Base
{

    public void displayMsg()
    {
        System.out.println("I'm in Base class - displayMsg()");
    }
}
```

The meaning of finally is :

```
class TestFinallyBlock{  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
  try{  
   int data=25/5;  
   System.out.println(data);  
  }  
  catch(NullPointerException e){System.out.println(e);}  
  finally{System.out.println("finally block is always executed");}  
  System.out.println("rest of the code...");  
  }  
}
```

in this exemple even if the try-catch is executed or not, what is inside of finally will always be executed.
The meaning of finalize:

```
class FinalizeExample{  
public void finalize(){System.out.println("finalize called");}  
public static void main(String[] args){  
FinalizeExample f1=new FinalizeExample();  
FinalizeExample f2=new FinalizeExample();  
f1=null;  
f2=null;  
System.gc();  
}}
```

before calling the Garbage Collector.